# Refresh parent page upon modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a modal which has this form. There's a button on the form which says "**Save & Exit**". Hitting it, the data is getting saved into the DB correctly via **ajax** but *how do I close the modal simultaneously and refresh the parent page?*

**Code to open modal**

```
<button type="button" class="float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#attribute_contact">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                        </button>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="attribute_contact" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

**Save & Close Button :-**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save & Close" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-success">
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#left_side_profile").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert("submitted");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: $('#left_side_profile').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              window.location.href = "editprofile.php";
            }
          });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: F12, what's in the console log?

Comment: `window.location.href = "editprofile.php";` is not doing the job ?

Comment: why close the modal if you are just going to refresh the page?  just refresh the page...

Answer (score 0):

In the success function first close the modal

```
$("#attribute_contact").modal('hide');
```

then reload the page

```
location.reload();

success: function (data) {
    $("#attribute_contact").modal('hide');
    location.reload();
}
```